# Is the following sentence in the active or passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

"The preparation for lodgment of an Environmental Impact Statement (EIS) to the Department of Planning ("Planning") continues."

Although I believe the previous sentence to be an agentless passive, it is supposedly in the active voice. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: "It continues"    Active voice.

Comment: The preparation.....of Planning = subject.   continues = verb.

Comment: In what country is "lodgment of [X] to [Y] a standard construction? In America, it would be "filing of [X] with [Y].

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. If you could edit your post to indicate *why* you believe the sentence to be an agentless passive, we may be able to help you identify the point of confusion. Otherwise, this question is likely to be closed as insufficiently researched.

Answer (score 3):

It is a beautiful example of distancing: used to make a sentence seem to be of high status and to remove any possibility of blame. What the writer is trying to avoid saying is

> **The environmental paper is being lodged.**  (passive)

or even

> **The lodgement of the environmental paper is being prepared.**  (passive)

One step more:

> **The preparation for the lodgement of the environmental paper continues**.

Thank you for the example, and for your question. You heard the inherent passive subtext.

Comment: +1 It might be characterized as a *de-agentive* construction: it employs  as subject an agent to which agency cannot be meaningfully attributed.

Comment: Might be helpful to clarify your implied *but grammatically it's not exactly a passive*